# onUpdate cloud function for UserRecord?

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I noticed that via cloud functions you are able to create onUpdate, onCreate, onDelete, etc.  to handle the lifecycle of a document. I don't see anything in their docs about doing the same for UserRecords. I see that they allow you to call onCreate and onDelete, but no onUpdate.

Has anyone been able to utilize onUpdate or similar for a UserRecord?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-functions

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions currently doesn't offer an onUpdate for Firebase Auth.  It's a commonly requested feature.  Please file a [feature request with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) if you would like to see this.